# how to add a push notification system like on stackoverflow (red number notification) in my rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, push-notification

I want to add a push notification pop-up like you see on stackoverflow. When a user comments you get a notification. I want to implement something similar on my rails 3 app. Is there a good gem for that? I saw other threads but they mention either the mailboxer or public activity gem. I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Search for push notifications and come back here when you have issues with implementing it in rails.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good gem available for implementing push notification in rails app:
https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub.

Ryan bates also have uploaded a railscasts for this:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub

You can also take help from this sample aaplication for implementing push notification.
https://github.com/aman199002/Push-Notification-App